# javascript array set deep value

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have an array called insurances. I set data in this array like this:

```
var insurances = {};

insurances[0] = {}
insurances[0]['id'] = 0;
```

etc...

Later on i want to change the id by doing this:

```
insurances[index]['id'] = insuranceId;
```

The index = 0 and the insuranceId = 1000;

Somehow it doesn't set the value (i get undefined). What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: could you post exact code to reproduce problem ? this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/qu7dX/) works well...

Comment: Could you post the section of code where you're setting the value of insuranceId? If the variable exists, but hasn't been given a value, you'll get 'undefined' rather than the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/pNAwk/

```
var insurances = {};

insurances[0] = {}
insurances[0]['id'] = 0;

insurances[0]['id'] = 1000;

alert( insurances[0]['id'] ); // alerts 1000
```

Note that if you intend to use indexed property names (0, 1, 2, ...), then an array literal is more appropriate:

```
var insurances = [];
```

Comment: Mm weird.. not in my setup. I will keep looking.